# Android calendar application not seen in the emulator.

Tags: android, android-emulator

Android source code contains code for calendar application perhaps it not seen in the emulator.

1. what is the work around to be done to view the calendar application.

I went through the source code, core.mk file doesn have a tag for calendar as well as calendar provider.

2. What can i do so as to include calendar application in my sdk.Any other steps need to be taken take?

Answers would be appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [walkthrough](http://caustiq.esoteriq.org/nb/archives/2009/01/28/index.html) on installing the calendar application in the emulator.  I haven't tried this myself.  For the app I wrote that worked with the calendar I just used an actual phone for all the testing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got an idea how I can access calender app from another application from your response.
but, my question was on how to include calender app and its provider in sdk.. Here is the procedure I followed and was easily able to load calender app and launch the same from emulator.
1) include calender and calenderprovider tag in core.mk(/build/target/product/core.mk) in a similar way as other apps.
2) run the cmds: "make sdk" on the src code folder.
3) load the sdk(path:/out/host/linux-x86/sdk/) and launch the emulator,its ready.

Thank you

Comment: Did the contents of the page I linked to titled "Loading The Calendar Application In The Android Emulator" not work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the link to the walkthrough (entitled "Loading The Calendar Application in the Android Emulator") is broken.  Is there another URL for that page?

Comment: That link gives an idea how u can make use of content provider of calender in different app. Is that u are looking for? or you have some other query ?

Comment: I would like to be able to sync the Android Calendar with other PIM's and therefore would like to access the Calendar Content Provider from different applications.